# Click event listener is being repeatedly triggered without any clicks?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a "Battleship" game with two grids made up of divs and am currently attempting to add a click event listener to all of the divs.

The issue that I am having is that the event listener is being repeatedly triggered (until every single div has been clicked) when I refresh my page and I can't understand why...

Here's the event listener in question:

```
 let aiGridCells = document.querySelectorAll(".ai-grid__game-cell");
 aiGridCells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", humanPlayer.humanAttack(cell.getAttribute('data-ai'),aiPlayer))
 });
```

Where humanPlayer is an object that has been generated by a factory function:

```
const humanPlayer = playerFactory('human');
```

```
import gameboardFactory from './gameboardFactory';

const playerFactory = (name) => {

    const playerBoard = gameboardFactory();

    const humanAttack = (cell, player) => {   // Where player is opponent
        if (player.playerBoard.gameBoard[cell].id !== 'miss') {
            player.playerBoard.receiveAttack(cell);
        };
    };

    const aiAttack = (player) => {   // Where player is opponent
        const availableCells = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < player.playerBoard.gameBoard.length; i++) {
            if (player.playerBoard.gameBoard[i].id === null) {
                availableCells.push(i);
            };
        };
        const attackCell = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableCells.length); 
        player.playerBoard.receiveAttack(attackCell);
    };

    return {
        name,
        playerBoard,
        humanAttack,
        aiAttack
    }

};

export default playerFactory;
```

and gameboardFactory is:

```
import shipFactory from './shipFactory';

const gameboardFactory = () => {
    const gameBoard = [];
    const shipYard = [];

    const init = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i<100; i++) {
            gameBoard.push({id: null})
        };
    };

    const checkValidCoordinates = (direction, start, end) => {
        if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            if ((start <= 9) && (end <= 9)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                let newStart = (start/10).toString(10);
                let newEnd = (end/10).toString(10);
                if ((newStart.charAt(0)) === (newEnd.charAt(0))) {
                    return true;
                };
            };
        } else {
            if ((start <= 9) && (end <= 9)) {
                return false
            } else if (start <= 9) {
                let newStart = start.toString(10);
                let newEnd = end.toString(10);
                if ((newStart.charAt(0)) === (newEnd.charAt(1))) {
                    return true;
                };
            } else {
                let newStart = start.toString(10);
                let newEnd = end.toString(10);
                if ((newStart.charAt(1)) === (newEnd.charAt(1))) {
                    return true;
                };
            };
        };
        return false
    };

    const checkIfShipPresent = (direction, start, end) => {
        if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                if (gameBoard[i].id !== null) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            return false;
        } else {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i += 10) {
                if (gameBoard[i].id !== null) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            return false;
        };
    };

    const placeShip = (id, direction, start, end) => {

        if (!checkValidCoordinates(direction, start, end)) {
            return;
        };

        if (checkIfShipPresent(direction, start, end)) {
            return;
        };
        
        const newShip = [];

        if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                gameBoard[i].id = id;
                newShip.push(i);
            };
        } else {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i += 10) {
                gameBoard[i].id = id;
                newShip.push(i);  
            };
        };
        
        shipYard.push(shipFactory(id, newShip));
    };

    const receiveAttack = (cell) => {

        console.log(cell)
       
        if (gameBoard[cell].id !== null) {
            const attackedShip = shipYard.filter((ship) => {
                return ship.id === gameBoard[cell].id;
            })[0];
            if (!attackedShip.hits.includes(cell)) {
                attackedShip.hits.push(cell);
            };
        } else {
            gameBoard[cell].id = 'miss';
        };
    };

    const checkIfAllShipsSunk = () => {
        let allShipsSunk = true;
        shipYard.forEach((ship) => {
            if (ship.isSunk() === false) {
                allShipsSunk = false;
            };
        });
        return allShipsSunk;
    };

    if (gameBoard.length === 0) {
        init();
    };

    return { 
        gameBoard,
        placeShip,
        receiveAttack,
        shipYard,
        checkIfAllShipsSunk
    };
};

export default gameboardFactory;
```

I'm completely lost to what the issue could be and have tried countless things to rectify it. Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to add actual function call as listener here:

```
 let aiGridCells = document.querySelectorAll(".ai-grid__game-cell");
 aiGridCells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", humanPlayer.humanAttack(cell.getAttribute('data-ai'),aiPlayer))
 });
```

So on your event listener initialization you actually call your function instead of passing it as a listener.

You can pass it like this instead:

```
 aiGridCells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener("click",  () => humanPlayer.humanAttack(cell.getAttribute('data-ai'),aiPlayer))
 });
```